# MVVM Light. Use same XAML/ViewModel as sub view in multiple XAML pages

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I am using MVVMLight and built a subview XAML page with view model. I want to use this code as a sub view in more then one XAML pages.

When I do, the locator obviously links to the one version. So when I make changes to the view model on one page, the other pages sub view model changes as well.

I have searched for solutions but can't seem to find a workaround for this.

My Viewmodel locator looks like this:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Page1ViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Page2ViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SubViewModel>();
}
```

And in Page1 and Page2 im connecting to the same SubViewModel which is obviously where the problem lies:

```
public class Page1ViewModel: MyBase_ViewModel
{
    IDataService services;
    public Page1ViewModel(IDataService serv)
    {
        services = serv;
        SubViewModel= Locator.SubViewModel;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was update my ViewModel Locator and add 2 new props which all get instance of sameviewmodel but using different keys:

```
public SubViewModel SubViewModel_Page1 { get { 
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SubViewModel>("any key.... 1"); } }
public SubViewModel SubViewModel_Page1 { get { 
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SubViewModel>("any key.... 2"); } }
```

Then in Page1 and Page2 initiator code in the view model I set the SubViewModel property which was bound to the Content Control in the view:

```
 public Page1VM(IDataService serv)
    {
        Page1SubViewModel = Locator.SubViewModel_Page1;
    }    

private SubViewModel _Page1SubViewModel;
public SubViewModel Page1SubViewModel
{
        get
        {
            return _Page1SubViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Page1SubViewModel == value)
                return;
            _Page1SubViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

and in the XAML in master pages:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SubViewModel}">
        <views:SubView />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding Page1SubViewModel}" />
```

I also had to remove DataContext attribute that was on the SubView XAML page as this is not required if binding to the ContentControl Content attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is retrieve your viewmodel with a key. That way you can get multiple instances of the same ViewModel Type and they all get stored in your ioc.

The syntax for this is as follows:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<T>(key);
```

What you set as key can be anything, as long as it is unique for the given type T.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how do I use content controls in multiple views where same xaml is used but with their own different view model?

Comment: By assigning the correct ViewModel ( retrieved with a key ) each time the View is loaded

Comment: How do i do that. As in the XAML im setting the datacontext to the ViewModel in Locator:

Comment: DataContext="{Binding SubViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"

Comment: Nope that is not possible, you need to set the datacontext of the view in the code behind of the view by retrieving the viewmodel from your ioc

Comment: but the sub view itself wont know which viewmodel to use. So i need to set the datacontext of the view from the ViewModel of the master pages? Not sure how I do that? is there a way i can reference the parent viewmodel?

Comment: Think i have it working now. Removed the datacontext line as i am setting the content via the ContentControl tag

Comment: <ContentControl Content="{Binding RecordViewModel}" />

Comment: This RecordViewModel is set during the initialiser of each Parent view and uses the ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance function along with individual Keys